# Google apps script cannot catch exception on "ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, exception, connection

I have a server and client side GAS app. The client side needs to run a function on the server. If for any reason, (like no internet connection), the connection is unsuccessful, I want it to gracefully alert the user. I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
try{
     google.script.run
       .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
       .myFunction();
     return;
   }
 catch(e){
   alert('Cannot connect to server: ' + e.message());
 }
```

Using Chrome 46, the console spits out the error correctly: "net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED". However, the alert doesn't appear. The console also says: "Uncaught NetworkError: Connection failure due to HTTP 0".

Why am I not able to catch the exception?

edit: as explained here (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/144326/try-catch-in-javascript-isnt-it-a-good-practice), maybe it has to do with the async nature of the calls. Can someone confirm this?

Comment: Have you tried using the function "withFailureHandler" ? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#failure_handlers

Comment: yes but its irrelevant here. withFailureHandler (f) hands over control to 'f' when the original function called throws an exception. Here, the original function is never called since the internet is disonnected before the request can be made. that is the condition i want to detect.

Answer (score -1):

I want to confirm whether Apps Script functions in a spreadsheet container-bound project can or cannot be called via google.script.run from within a JavaScript function in an HTML template that was loaded by the HTMLService. My initial findings indicate "not" (see below), but I might be missing something.

The google.script.run call, when made from within the JS function called by the onclick handler, consistently routes to the error handler function, with the following error code: NetworkError: Connection failure due to HTTP 0.

If I call the google.script.run code directly from the onclick handler of a button, it does run. I'd prefer to be able to use it in a function, so that I can build up a set of data to pass into the real method I'm planning for the implementation.

The error you see is because you close the sidebar with that line, severing connection to the server-side script.

Comment: This has nothing to do with any sidebar. I don't have a sidebar in my project. the client side is served using htmlservice as a webapp. there is no spreadsheet container either.